# What was the role of the Crane Corps in The Great Wall?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-great-wall

The blue female soldiers (Crane Corps) jumping from the wall to attack one or two monsters in [The Great Wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Great_Wall_(film)) seem to be a complete waste of well trained forces: they can kill one, maybe two or three monsters on each jump, and are apparently eaten quite often

**Do they have a particular role explained in the movie, and the reason for this apparently ineffective tactical move?**

Comment: I haven't seen the film so not answering, but I would assume they have been proven to be effective against more regular opponents in the past, and generally you stick with what you know.

Answer (score 1):

If you have seen complete movie then you know that at the end,

> Commander Lin Mae makes use of her Crane Corp abilities to swing from rope and get closer to Queen.

Apart from that Crane Corp is used to close combat Taotei. 
Death squad is used in similar way to attract Taotei and then cut them using blades within wall.

As there is no other mention of Crane Corp role other than defending close attack, in my opinion it's purely for demonstrating army's capability.